# $expand=permissions failed with notSupported error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search#optional-query-parameters) clearly states that this endpoint supports `$expand` to modify the search result:

```
users/{user-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')?$expand=permissions
```

But the request returns the following body in its response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "The request is not supported by the system.",    
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "30fc9988-6f4f-46ba-a5b4-91b150c4a1a5",     
            "date": "2017-11-17T02:30:49"
        }
    }
}
```

This is also the case for other relationships. Though trying to expand `createdByUser` results in a `BadRequest`.

We want to do this request to avoid doing subsequent requests. Because at the moment we use a SharePoint `ListItemUniqueId` (due to backwards comparability) to find the corresponding `DriveItem`. Then we want to retrieve the permissions of this `DriveItem`. But right now we need to do two requests to achieve this.

We also can't use `/users/{user-id}/drive/items` because it does not support `$filter`.

Are we misunderstanding the docs or is this an issue on the Microsoft Graph side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot expand the `permissions` collection. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_permissions#remarks):

> The permissions relationship of `DriveItem` cannot be expanded as part of a call to get `DriveItem` or a collection of `DriveItems`. You must access the permissions property directly.

The reason `$expand=createdByUser` returns a `BadRequest` is because it is already expanded by default.

Properties that are not supported are in `$expand` on the `/search` endpoint are:

- `children` - Since `/search` returns files, this logically wouldn't make any sense here.
- `lastModifiedByUser` - included by default
- `content` - logically the content of each file wouldn't make sense to be included in a collection of `DriveItems`

Thumbnails can be expanded however (`$expand=thumbnails`).

Comment: Thank you very much Marc. I just found it in the docs and wanted to edit the question or provide the answer myself ^^.
But why can't it be expanded? Because of crossing service boundaries? If so what services would be involved? As I understand it OneDrive for Business is actually part of SharePoint and it also inherits its default permissions roles.

Comment: I'm not 100% on the cause but I believe it has to do with `search()` returning multiple facet types. Since each facet uses different permission entities, you would end up with each element having containing a property of a different type. For example, remote files that are shared with you would show up with a different permissions object than files in your own drive.